# Java LinkedList rotation

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a custom class that extends the java.util.LinkedList class and adds a new method called rotate(). The rotate() method should rotate the elements in the list by a specified number of positions, similar to the way the Unix rotate command works.

For example:

```java
RotatingList<Integer> list = new RotatingList<>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
list.rotate(2);
System.out.println(list);  // Outputs: [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

I have the basic structure of the RotatingList class set up, but I'm having trouble with the implementation of the rotate() method. How can I efficiently rotate the elements in the list by a specified number of positions?"

Comment: `while (n --> 0) addFirst(pollLast());`

Comment: `Collections.rotate(this, n);`.

Comment: Elegant, @shmosel. You will want to apply a modulo operation to `n` first so that when I specify 65432 and the list length is 5, you perform the operation twice, not 65432 times. Since the question asked  "efficiently".

Comment: [How to rotate element in list java? - W3schools.blog](https://www.w3schools.blog/how-to-rotate-element-in-list-java). Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn that you are supposed to search before asking a question here. There’s a lot more to be found. If you search and find something and don’t know how to apply it to your situation, your question is welcome, and we already have a better starting point for helping you than we have without it.

Comment: What is your current implementation of rotate and why does it give you problems?